# Angular class not applied when using javascript literal

Tags: css, angular, typescript, template-literals

When a class is added in the template literal it is not changing the style of the element:

> comp.html

```
<div data-js = "tutorial" class ="center main">
    
</div>
```

> comp.scss

```
.testt {
    color: red;
}
```

> comp.ts

```
public tutorial: Element;
constructor() { }

ngOnInit() {

    this.tutorial = document.querySelector("[data-js='tutorial']");
    this.tutorial.innerHTML = `
        <h1 class = "testt">
            Welcome
        </h1>
    `;
}
```

**`<h1>` is not colored red**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by default component emulate native scoping of styles by **adding an attribute containing surrogate id** to the Host Element and pre-processing the style rules provided via styles or styleUrls, and adding the new Host Element attribute to all selectors.

[image]

so you can set component encapsulation to none

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

or add the class in the global style file so the class will effect any element in your project have that class

*style.scss*

```css
.testt {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you explain what does `encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None` do ?

Comment: you can check the other option for encapsulation here  https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation#description

Comment: encapsulation:ViewEncapsulation.None means don't restrict the css to just this component so the whole site will be affected by any css in the component's css. ::ng-deep will restrict the css to affecting only children of the component, not the whole site.

Comment: @AdrianBrand thanks for the feed back I'm still think the best wayis to add the style to the global style file so he don't have a style problem in future

Comment: Which is what I recommended in my answer

Answer (score 3):

The injected html is not part of the component so the components CSS does not affect it. use

```
::ng-deep .testt {
    color: red;
}
```

or add the css to a global style sheet

Comment: Thank you. Can you provide how to create a global style sheet in angular ?, or if there already one automatically created. First thought is to create a style sheet and embed it in index.html. Is there a better or more common way ?

Comment: if you add the style in the global style file you don't need to create a style sheet and embed it in index.html because it 's the same result

Comment: Is the automatically created `global.scss` the global style sheet ? If no, how to create a global style sheet ? Is creating It in the root folder enough to make it global ? Or is there a specific folder where all global style files should be placed ?

Comment: you can create multiple scss file then importe these files in the global style file or by angular.json the fill url in style array

Comment: There is usually a styles.scss file created in the src folder when you create a new Angular project

Comment: @AdrianBrand Also, shouldn't we use the `:host` selector In order to scope the specified style to the current component and all its descendants? otherwise the style can bleed into other components. https://angular.io/guide/component-styles